# DJANGO - Exception on filter by "hour_gte" and "hour_lte" - Unsupported lookup 'hour' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Here is my django model:

```
class Readings(models.Model):
       val = models.FloatField(default=0)
       created_dt = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now I want to select the rows between 2 dates, called `start_date` and `end_date` and for each date I want to select rows only in a specific time range (like `04:00-10:00`).

I have the follwing parameters -
start_date (datetime object) example "2017-08-04 18:30:00"
end date (datetime object)
start_hour (integer)
end_hour (integer)

My Query 
 `Readings.objects.filter(created_dt__gte=start_date,created_dt__lte=end_date, created_dt__hour__gte= start_hour, created_dt__hour__lte=end_hour)`
But it raises an exception called **Unsupported lookup 'hour' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted**

Comment: Hi R8B8m, welcome to SO. Your code sample is not self-standing, one cannot run it and reproduce your issue, since `model` is not provided. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @snake_charmer thanks , I have provided my django model in the description, should i provide anything else too ?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest to define both dates and times in one timezone / datetime object and filter objects accordingly. I use [__range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range) to achieve the result and probably it would be more efficient since in one query you will fetch all the desired information:

```
from django.utils import timezone as tz
start_dt = tz.now()  # you should tune the value
end_dt = tz.now() + tz.timedelta(days=1)  # you should tune the value
Readings.objects.filter(created_dt__range=(start_dt, end_dt))
```

this will hit db one time and return all the values in that datetime range.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but wont this just filter by 2 date ranges ? For all the dates between the 2 date ranges , i want to select only the rows  between some starting and ending hour. 
Example.  Lets assume i have following data
 2017-10-20 05:30:00
 2017-10-20 06:30:00
 2017-10-20 07:30:00
 2017-10-20 08:30:00
 2017-10-29 09:30:00
 2017-10-29 10:30:00
 2017-10-30 05:30:00
 2017-10-30 06:30:00
 2017-10-30 07:30:00
 2017-10-30 08:30:00
 2017-10-30 09:30:00
 2017-10-30 10:30:00
Now if i want only data where  29 <= date <= 30 and 05 <= hour <= 07

Answer (score 0):

```
Readings.objects.filter(created_dt__range=["YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM","YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM"])
```

hope this works

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think these will only filter dates between 2 time ranges and not filter on basis of hours too.

Answer (score 0):

With `USE_TZ = True` in your settings and solving your problem in the local timezone, if this is what you want:

```
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone

tz = get_current_timezone()
start_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 5)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 11) # the day you want + 1
Readings.objects.filter(created_dt__gte=start_date,
                        created_dt__lt=end_date,
                        created_dt__hour__gte=4,
                        created_dt__hour__gte=10)
```

Note that the start and and dates are localized datetimes (not dates). Also, `__hour` and friends use the local timezone when `USE_TZ = True`, according to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#hour).

Comment: Thanks for the answer , this is exactly what i was trying to do but it raises an Exception :
"Unsupported lookup 'hour' for DateTimeField or join on the field not permitted."

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Django as a Webserver+Gunicorn+Nginx.What I do for some complex back-end based webservices, I normally use SQL requests for talking with the db (MariaDb,Mysql,PostGreSql..) I prefer this way, I honestly can't use that django admin panel to do productive stuff. Anyway for dates I like to use the [python Arrow lib](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) . What I would suggest if you have the time is:

1) You design your SQL code (Select request), should be something like this

```
        select created_dt from Readings 
where created_dt between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27 23:59:59.999'
```

2) You can import Arrow it makes your life easier when playing with dates, example:

```
import arrow
mydate = arrow.now().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

3) You use a SQL connector and execute your sql request:

```
import MySQLdb
myhost = 'xx.xx.xx.xx' # IP
myuser = 'xxxxxxxyour usernamexxxxxxxxxxxx'
mypassword = '****your pass***********'
sql = "select created_dt from Readings where created_dt between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27 23:59:59.999'"
db = 'your_database_name'
connection = MySQLdb.connect(myhost,myuser,mypassword,db,use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql) # your results are in the cursor
#connection.commit() # you don't need this
connection.close
for your_result in cursor[0]:
    mydate = your_result[0]
```

Just a reminder you need to use dico = True with the proper version of the MySql connector if you want to call get fields data by name, something like(your_result['**My_field_name**'])

If you are displaying the data, you will be recoding the View.py class in your Django projects. 
Hope it helps, good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer , it's pretty helpful but i was looking for something with django queryset .